# Aggregations in MySql vs ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, aggregation

I am working on an e-commerce website where a user can show interest on available products and we store it as a lead in MySQL table. This Leads table consists of millions of records and grows by 8 records per minute. Table structure is as follows:

```
LeadId | ProductId | UserId | RequestDate(DateTime)
```

I have a requirement to allow only x leads in 30 days. So I need to aggregate data to get the count of leads in last 30 days and block the user accordingly. I need suggestions on following approaches:

1. MySQL aggregation query: I can add an index on UserId & RequestDate fields and get the count of 30 days.
2. Using ElasticSearch: I can create a document with these fields and run aggregations on that.
3. Summary Table: Create a summary table on daily basis or hourly basis and get computed data. This might be complex to implement for aggregation on data of last x units of time.

I am seeing performance benefits in approach-2 and maintenance benefits in approach-1. Which of these approaches should I use?

Comment: You should use the solution that best conforms to your teams skills and experience.

Comment: Our team has equal experience on both elasticsearch and mysql technologies. Will be it be okay to use elastic search for this amount of data (around 10 million)?

Answer (score 0):

Move all leads older then 30 days to an archive table to reduce the amount of rows. Make a positive counter for each user and increase it every day, when you copy the data to the archive. Decrease it if an user adds an lead. If the counter is zero, there cant be added any further leads from this user.